# Can I use a hashmark in .htaccess URL?

Tags: jquery, apache, .htaccess, hash

I'm using [jquery address](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/) and everything is working great except for one small issue inside my .htaccess file.  I'd like to redirect one of my urls that includes a hashmark to another URL.

Here is my current setup using redirect (that works):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule view_profile=(.*)$ view_profile.php?id=$1
```

If a user logs in at any point this URL doesn't work because my jquery address looks like this:

```
http://localhost/#view_profile=5
```

If I add the leading hash as part of my rewriterule it breaks.  Does anyone know if it's possible to use a leading hashmark as part of the URL?

Comment: Using #marks is deeply evil and should be avoided. Despite what twitter etc have done - see rationale here: http://www.webmonkey.com/2011/02/gawker-learns-the-hard-way-why-hash-bang-urls-are-evil/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No you can't do this, as anything after the # is a fragment identifier and therefore not sent to the server.

See the RFC on URIs here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.5